# Simultaneous editing of the document

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I use Microsoft Graph API to modify Excel document located in OneDrive folder. For example I call different method to alter the document (create worksheets, modify range). And the most time it works fine.

But when I open the document in editor (web version or desktop) all Microsoft Graph methods (POST, PATCH) start to fail with HTTP:405 or "isTrusted": true in Graph Explorer. What is more it happens not always: for example first time it fails but if I close the doc and open it again it could work or vice versa.

And in case when it works I see tooltip in editor that Guest is modifying the document. Why guest but not me (I'm authenticated in Graph Explorer under the same account)?

Are there any tricks or guides how modify already opened excel document in an editor via Microsoft Graph?

---

**Updated (22 June 2018)**:
Unfortunately the error returned back. With opened document in the editor I get HTTP: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Are you using `workbook-session-id`? Could you provide an actual JSON payload you're getting?

Comment: I don't use workbook-session-id. Very strange but now I can't reproduce the issue with error HTTP: 405. In case when I got the error there was text/html response. Right now there is only one issue: when I modify opened document via Graph API I see that Guest user editing online (not me).

Comment: The guest user is a known issue. My understanding is that the "guest" is just Microsoft Graph operating on your behalf. Obviously, this isn't the best experience but I certainly understand the complexity that team faces when it comes to handling public APIs and identity. Hopefully, they resolve it in the near future.

Comment: You should absolutly look into using `workbook-session-id`. It has a huge impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use workbook-session-id. Problem was that create session also failed in case of opened document. It's strange that issue is gone. Maybe the team rolled up an update.